# execvp arguments

Tags: c, unix, exec

Helllo everybody,

I have this example code:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
   execvp(argv[2],&argv[2]);
   perror("Error");
}else {
wait(NULL);

}
```

From `man exec` I understand that

> " The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed".

So, if I execute my program this way:

```
./a.out 5 ls
```

The command ls will be executed.

What about the second argument? the manual says

> "The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer"

and I don't see a NULL pointer here nor I understan what is the function of `&argv[2]` here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

The second argument to `execvp` is the array of `char*`s that will become the resulting process's `argv`.  In order for `execvp` to know how long this array is, the last "real" element must be followed by `NULL`, e.g., in order to pass `{"foo", "bar"}` as the new `argv`, the second argument to `execvp` must refer to the array `{"foo", "bar", NULL}`.  In your case, as the `argv` array passed to your program's `main` is already terminated by a `NULL` entry of its own, you can pass `&argv[2]` to `execvp` directly without having to add on a `NULL` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a.out, it most likely has a `main` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

/* argv contains this. */
argv[0] == "a.out"
argv[1] == "5"
argv[2] == "ls"
argv[3] == NULL /* Here is your terminator. */
```

So when you are passing `argv[2]` to `execvp` everything is in place, but the array starts at 2 (starts with `ls`).